# polar coordinates : integration over negative radius

Tags: integration

In polar coordinates , if I want to integrate the function 
$$\frac{2}{1+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$
over the quadrant of circle that lies within
$$\theta=\pi\,\,\,\, to\,\,\,\, \theta= \ 3\pi/2$$
either we do 
$$\int\limits_{\pi}^{3\pi/2}\int\limits_{0}^{1}\frac{2 r\,\,dr\,\,d\theta}{1+r}$$
or
$$\int\limits_{0}^{\pi/2}\int\limits_{-1}^{0}\frac{2 r\,\,dr\,\,d\theta}{1+r}$$
The question is :  why the limits of r is from  -1 to 0 in the second solution , why not from 0 to -1 ?

Another question : in the second solution do we have to take absolute value of r inside the integration ? (because we take the absolute value of the jacobian ?)

Comment: No, $r$ may not be negative, it is a positive square root. (Or if you really want that, the denominator must be $1-r$.)

Comment: ok..I want to understand the limits of r .. if the denominator is $$1-r$$  or we have any other function inside the integration that does not have a problem when subsitution.. then if I want to integrate over the third quadrant but taking limits of 
$$\theta \,\,\,\,from\,\,\, 0 \,\,\,to\,\,\, \pi/2$$ , what will be the limits of r ? 
from -1 to 0 or from 0 to -1 ? and why ?

Comment: $0$ to $-1$, with a negative Jacobian.